# Getting this error Uncaught Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to move my div(bar) as my states gets updated using props. but this error occurs.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { data as TableData } from "../Table/alan_requested_format";
import "./styles.css";

export const Playhead = (props) => {
  const [incVal, setIncVal] = useState(0);

  let width = 15;
  let incrementedValue = (width / TableData.duration) * props.currentTime;

  console.log("incrementedValue", incrementedValue);
  setIncVal(incrementedValue);

  const style = {
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    border: "6px solid #ffffff",
    height: "75px",
    width: `${width}px`,
    borderRadius: "5px",
    position: "absolute",
    left: { incVal },
    padding: "0px 4px 0px 4px",
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div class="vl" style={style}></div>
    </>
  );
};
```

When I try to run this code the code bursts. The whole web page got crashed.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote your setter `setIncVal` inside the render function (function component's body), therefore you actually trigger state change on every render which causes the infinite loop.

I believe you wanted to trigger this change only on `currentTime` change, therefore use the proper API with `useEffect`:

```
let width = 15;

export const Playhead = (props) => {
  const [incVal, setIncVal] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let incrementedValue = (width / TableData.duration) * props.currentTime;

    console.log("incrementedValue", incrementedValue);
    setIncVal(incrementedValue);
  }, [props.currentTime]);

  const style = {
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    border: "6px solid #ffffff",
    height: "75px",
    width: `${width}px`,
    borderRadius: "5px",
    position: "absolute",
    left: { incVal },
    padding: "0px 4px 0px 4px",
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div class="vl" style={style}></div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export const Playhead = (props) => {

  let incrementedValue = props.TableData.duration / window.innerWidth;

  const style = {
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    border: "1px solid #ffffff",
    height: "95px",
    borderWidth: '2px',
    width: "2px",
    borderRadius: "5px",
    position: "absolute",
    left: incrementedValue * props.currentTime,
    padding: "0px 4px 0px 4px",
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div class="vl" style={style}></div>
    </>
  );
};
```